# Excel macro that delete input in one cell depending on the input in one other cell

Tags: vba, excel

I regularly receive worksheets with cells containing the value "not know". I want a macro to easily delete the value in each cell that is two cells down from the cells with input "not know".

This is my current macro.. as you see I am a real beginner :/

```
Sub Makro4()
'
' Delete input in cell below a cell containing "not know"
'

'
    Cells.Find(What:="not know", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        On Error Resume Next
    Selection.ClearContents
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Love some support!

Comment: If "not know" was in cell **B9,**  exactly which cells should be cleared??

Comment: Three cells down, so B12!

Answer (score 0):

The following should help

```
Dim i as Long, Rng as Range
Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10000")

For i = 1 to 10000
    if Rng.Cell(i,1).Value = "dont know" Then
        Rng.Cell(i + 2, 1).ClearContents
    end if
Next i
```

Comment: I am not able to get to work.

I receive Runtime error number 9.

Sub Makro1()
 
Dim i As Long, Rng As Range
Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10000")

For i = 1 To 10000
    If Rng.Cell(i, 1).Value = "dont know" Then
        Rng.Cell(i + 2, 1).ClearContents
    End If
Next i



End Sub

Comment: Please be a bit more specific in your response. Does it give an error? Does it not give an error? Does it delete the wrong cells, does it delete only part of the cells....?

Comment: Sorry,
It gives an error. Saying: Körfel nr '9'.:
Index is outside the interval (translated from Swedish :)

My testsheet looks like this..

cell A1 and C1: "dont know"
cell B1 and D1: "6"
cell A2 and C2: #error
cell B2 and D2: 1

I want the macro to delete cell A2 and C2 based on the fact that A1 and C1 has the input "dont know"..

hope I am clear enought..

Comment: In that case, just decrease the size of the loop and test. Trap the error using a breakpoint and see which value of i causes it.

Comment: I am still not able to get it to work.

I think I solved Runtime error 9 since I changed Worksheets("Sheet1") to Swedish, -> Worksheets("Blad1").

Now the error occurs at   If Rng.Cell(i, 1).Value = "dont know" Then

Runtime error is 438 "object doesn't support this property or method"

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
Sub luxations()
    Dim rBig As Range, rLittle As Range, r As Range
    Set rBig = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Set rLittle = Nothing
    For Each r In rBig
    If r.Text = "not know" Then
        If rLittle Is Nothing Then
            Set rLittle = r
        Else
            Set rLittle = Union(r, rLittle)
        End If
    End If

    If Not rLittle Is Nothing Then
        rLittle.Offset(3, 0).Clear
    End If
    Next
End Sub
```